# Access local storage iTunes music (ios) within expo / React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, itunes

I'm building a music player using React Native / Expo and need access to play iTunes music from local storage (outside my app directory), target platform is iOS (Android support is optional first).

How can I list (and open) all local iTunes music files within Expo/React Native?